# simple formatting issue, 2 interfering environments

Tags: environments, dialogue

I am using the Frankensteins dialogue environment as well as the `mdframed` environment in order to highlight interesting parts of the dialogue.
I would like that these two environments don't interfere with each other. Ideally I would only like to have a line on the right when the `siderules` environment is active.

This is the `mdframed` environment layout.

```
\newmdenv[
  topline=false,
  bottomline=false,
  leftline=false,
  skipabove=1pt,
  skipbelow=1pt,
]{siderules}
```

This is the plain text in .tex

```
\speak{Subject E}
Well you know, we do some stuff with our employees. You know, some typical ... We offer free lunches. We have some retreats sometimes. You know, free candy, things like that. But you know, when you're a start-up, you're so busy and you don't ... I mean, you cannot do much more than that, really.

\speak{Moritz}
Sure, I understand. So you also did not look like, for example, for this Indian company, did you check if they look at work hours or at work conditions or something? Or if they give free lunch?
\begin{siderules}
\speak{Subject E}
No, no, no. Never. We never looked what our partners did or not. If anything, some of our customers wanted us to ... I mean, it's borderline corruption, almost, that they wanted us to pay them up front a large sum to get their business. And then they would deduct our prize from that. But they wanted it up front.

\speak{Moritz}
So how did you deal with this stuff?

\speak{Subject E}
We tried to negotiate as much as possible the price down.
\end{siderules}
```

Here is an image of the output. I would like that it looks nicer. Why are the double points missing?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For frames around environments you can use the `\surroundwithmdframed` command. This surrounds all environments with the specified name with a frame. To surround only some parts, you can define a second dialogue command with a different name.

An additional problem is that `mdframed` sets `leftmargin`, which is used by `dialogue` for the hanging indent. To recreate the indent you can unindent the first line of a `\speak` line by defining a new command containing the indent and the original speak command, which is not very clean but it works as expected.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dialogue}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\surroundwithmdframed\[
  topline=false,
  bottomline=false,
  leftline=false,
  skipabove=1pt,
  skipbelow=1pt,
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
\]{mddialogue}
\newenvironment{mddialogue}{\begin{dialogue}}{%
    \end{dialogue}\ignorespacesafterend
}
\newcommand{\mdspeak}[1]{\speak{\hspace{-20pt}#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{dialogue}
\speak{Subject E}
Well you know, we do some stuff with our employees. You know, some typical ... We offer free lunches. We have some retreats sometimes. You know, free candy, things like that. But you know, when you're a start-up, you're so busy and you don't ... I mean, you cannot do much more than that, really.

\speak{Moritz}
Sure, I understand. So you also did not look like, for example, for this Indian company, did you check if they look at work hours or at work conditions or something? Or if they give free lunch?
\end{dialogue}
\begin{mddialogue}
\mdspeak{Subject E}
No, no, no. Never. We never looked what our partners did or not. If anything, some of our customers wanted us to ... I mean, it's borderline corruption, almost, that they wanted us to pay them up front a large sum to get their business. And then they would deduct our prize from that. But they wanted it up front.

\mdspeak{Moritz}
So how did you deal with this stuff?

\mdspeak{Subject E}
We tried to negotiate as much as possible the price down.
\end{mddialogue}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]